# Xlib : how to get CAPS LOCK status

Tags: linux, x11, xlib, xserver

How to retrieve CAPS Lock key information using Xlib if it is on or off ?

Comment: Just found the answer and posted in my blog http://levonp.blogspot.com/2010/08/retrieving-caps-lock-info-using-xlib.html

Comment: Be aware that the code you have reports the remapped key, meaning that if the user has moved the CapsLock symbol/function to F1 or something (possibly using the physical CapsLock key for Hyper, like I am, or whatever), than the state of the F1 key would be reported.